# Python - How to make tasks run asynchronously using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was trying to run 2 tasks at the same time for a single client from the list but it doesn't work as expected - the tasks still ran synchronously (please see `Output`). Can you help me understand what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio


async def do_b(client):
    print('{}: doing b...'.format(client))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('{}: b is done!'.format(client))


async def do_a(client):
    print('{}: doing a...'.format(client))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('{}: a is done!'.format(client))


async def loop_a():
    clients = ['CLIENT-1', 'CLIENT-2', 'CLIENT-3', 'CLIENT-4', 'CLIENT-5']

    for client in clients:
        task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(do_a(client))
        task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(do_b(client))

        await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(loop_a())
    loop.close()
```

## Output

```
CLIENT-1: doing a...
CLIENT-1: doing b...
CLIENT-1: a is done!
CLIENT-1: b is done!
CLIENT-2: doing a...
CLIENT-2: doing b...
CLIENT-2: a is done!
CLIENT-2: b is done!
CLIENT-3: doing a...
CLIENT-3: doing b...
CLIENT-3: a is done!
CLIENT-3: b is done!
CLIENT-4: doing a...
CLIENT-4: doing b...
CLIENT-4: a is done!
CLIENT-4: b is done!
CLIENT-5: doing a...
CLIENT-5: doing b...
CLIENT-5: a is done!
CLIENT-5: b is done!
```

EDIT:

Another question. How do I make it execute like this which does not follow their order in the list? Because currently, `CLIENT-1` is being blocked by `CLIENT-2`, same as the other clients and I was trying to avoid that. Is this possible?

```
CLIENT-1: doing a...
CLIENT-2: doing a...
CLIENT-1: doing b...
CLIENT-3: doing a...
CLIENT-1: a is done!
CLIENT-1: b is done!
CLIENT-2: a is done!
CLIENT-3: a is done!
CLIENT-2: doing b...
CLIENT-2: b is done!
CLIENT-3: doing b...
CLIENT-3: b is done!
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but this site/book helped me understand `asyncio`. Maybe it will help you with your problem. https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/control.html

Comment: `a` and `b` are running at the same time and the output shows that. clients 1,2,3,4,5 are running sequentially because you have an `await asyncio.gather` between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are running at the same time and the output shows that. Clients 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are running sequentially because there is an `await asyncio.gather` between them.

You can merge all of the tasks into one list to make them run at the same time:

```
async def loop_a():
    clients = ['CLIENT-1', 'CLIENT-2', 'CLIENT-3', 'CLIENT-4', 'CLIENT-5']

    tasks = []
    for client in clients:
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(do_a(client)))
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(do_b(client)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Now it prints:

```
CLIENT-1: doing a...
CLIENT-1: doing b...
CLIENT-2: doing a...
CLIENT-2: doing b...
CLIENT-3: doing a...
CLIENT-3: doing b...
CLIENT-4: doing a...
CLIENT-4: doing b...
CLIENT-5: doing a...
CLIENT-5: doing b...
CLIENT-1: a is done!
CLIENT-2: a is done!
CLIENT-3: b is done!
CLIENT-1: b is done!
CLIENT-3: a is done!
CLIENT-2: b is done!
CLIENT-4: a is done!
CLIENT-5: b is done!
CLIENT-4: b is done!
CLIENT-5: a is done!
```

Comment: I have another question. How do I make them execute without following the order in the list because currently `CLIENT-1` is being blocked by `CLIENT-2`? @zvone

Answer (score 1):

First, the two tasks *aren't* running synchronously, as you can see from the fact that `doing b...` keeps showing up in between `doing a...` and `a is done!`.

Each pair of tasks is finishing before the next client starts, but that's because you're explicitly asking for that to happen. If you don't want to `await` each pair, just… don't `await` each pair. For example:

```
futs = []
for client in clients:
    futs.append(asyncio.ensure_future(do_a(client)))
    futs.append(asyncio.ensure_future(do_b(client)))
await asyncio.gather(*futs)
```